# Method in another class 'does not exist' compiler error

Tags: c#, class

I'm sure this is something simple. I'm not very familiar with C# (I'm actually porting this over from C++).

I am calling the method CalculateLines which is in the class CalculateFrontages after an 'OK' click (snippet):

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //     MessageBox.Show("User clicked OK");

        string value = MSTGapThresholdInMeters.Text;
        MSTGapValue = Int32.Parse(value);

        MainWindowViewModel.RedTLS =  CalculateFrontages.CalculateLines(MainWindowViewModel.RedArmy, Map.MetersPerPixel, MSTGapValue);
        MainWindowViewModel.BlueTLS = CalculateFrontages.CalculateLines(MainWindowViewModel.BlueArmy, Map.MetersPerPixel, MSTGapValue);

        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
```

And this is the method, CalculateLines, which is in another class, CalculateFrontages, that I want to call (snippet):

```
namespace TacticalAILib
{
public class CalculateFrontages
{

    static int[] U;

    private static TacLineStruct CalculateLines(List<MATEUnit> Army, double MetersPerPixel, int MSTGapValue)
    {

        int TempFrom, TempTo;
        float TempWeight;
        int NumEdges = 0;
        double Threshold = MetersPerPixel * MSTGapValue;
        U = new int[Army.Count];
```

And it's throwing this compiler error:

> Error CS0426  The type name 'CalculateLines' does not exist in the type 'CalculateFrontages'

I assume it's a scope error, or a declaration error. I just don't know enough about this.

Comment: Well, it's `private`, isn't it.

Comment: `private static TacLineStruct CalculateLines...` If it is private it cant be referenced outside the class.  That error message doesnt seem to match that code though.

Comment: *"Error CS0122  'CalculateFrontages.CalculateLines()' is inaccessible due to its protection level"* rather, no ?

Comment: Or there is another class named `CalculateFrontages` in another namespace than `TacticalAILib`

Comment: (There is much value in assuming the best of your readers when asking a question. If you tell people you assume they will downvote unreasonably, then downvotes may be the result of that remark. Please try to omit unnecessary and conversation material from questions, and stick to the problem itself. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method's accessibility level is `private`, that means other any request can not reach that function exept the owner class. If you update it to `public`, you can reach it from anywhere..

Comment: Thanks for supplying the answer.